# CodeceptJS not accepting proxy settings

Tags: selenium, proxy, webdriver-io, codeceptjs

I want to pass CodeceptJS requests through an external proxy.  I followed the instructions in the [docs](https://codecept.io/helpers/WebDriverIO/#connect-through-proxy).

In the logging I see indications the proxy is being passed on, but its not being used by `selenium-standalone` to proxy requests.

```
10:56:25.020 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.commandhandler.BeginSession@7d95346a
10:56:25.020 INFO - /session: Executing POST on /session (handler: BeginSession)
10:56:25.024 INFO - Capabilities are: Capabilities {browserName: chrome, handlesAlerts: true, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, loggingPrefs: org.openqa.selenium.logging..., proxy: {httpProxy: http://<myproxy>..., proxyType: manual, socksPassword: <my password>..., socksUsername: <my username>}, requestOrigins: {name: webdriverio, url: http://webdriver.io, version: 4.10.2}, rotatable: true}
10:56:25.024 INFO - Capabilities {browserName: chrome, handlesAlerts: true, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, loggingPrefs: org.openqa.selenium.logging..., proxy: {httpProxy: http://<myproxy>..., proxyType: manual, socksPassword: <my password>..., socksUsername: <my username>}, requestOrigins: {name: webdriverio, url: http://webdriver.io, version: 4.10.2}, rotatable: true} matched class org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
```

- CodeceptJS version: 1.1.5
- NodeJS Version: 8.0
- Operating System: mac
- Protractor || WebDriverIO || Nightmare version (if related)
  selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1
- Configuration file:

`"helpers": {
      "WebDriverIO": {
        "url": "https://caworkcompcoverage.com",
        "browser": "chrome",
        "desiredCapabilities": {
            "proxy": {
                "proxyType": "manual",
                "httpProxy": "http://proxy:8010",
                "socksUsername": "my username",
                "socksPassword": "my password"
            }
        }
      }
    },`

Comment: This may be related to https://superuser.com/questions/902620/google-chrome-proxy-settings-with-username-and-password